# SignalR Vs. Websocket In Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I'm Kind Of New In Real-Time Programming.
I Just Want To Know Which One Is Better To Use For And In Performance In Asp.Net Core 2
Thank You So Much

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is a framework for working with websockets (or other real-time strategies such as long-polling, events, etc.). Websockets are the underlying technology. You need something like SignalR or similar to work with websockets.

Comment: I'm currently using System.Net.WebSocket and there is no force to use SignalR.
I heard using websocket directly might be better than using SignalR but I don't know that.